# Rotating a table object

Tags: excel-2007

For the sake of clarity, I'm not looking for the transpose function, like has been asked previously on this site quite a few times.

The excel table object (Insert>Table) is exactly what I want. All I'd like to do is rotate the table for readability purposes. Currently, I have far more columns than rows, and it would improve readability a lot if the axes were flipped so that the vertical aspect of the scroll wheel could be used while looking at the data

My current data is a list of machining jobs. Each row is one job for one customer, and each column is a different parameter corresponding to settings/cost/material. With the tables, I'm able to dynamically sort the jobs in the table based on each of the parameters in a very helpful manner. This is the most important thing: to continue being able to dynamically sort based on the parameters. So far, I have been unable to find a way to transfer dynamic sorting to row headings instead of column headings.

Comment: For someone that habitually works on wide worksheets, there are mice that allow you to tilt the scroll wheel to the right or left for horizontal scrolling. Freezing frames is another productivity tool.

Comment: Yea, it's not a huge deal to have to scroll horizontally. It's really more about being able to see more information at once due to the way words are longer than they are tall. I'm typing this right now on a 1024x768 monitor.